# Parse with Search Bar and Search Display controller iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Saw this iOS Swift tutorial in Ray Wenderlich using Search Bar and Search Display 
controller but it uses local data.

(http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift).

I need it to load data from Parse, a User object class, column username.

Any clue how to start, what to change from the example above ?

thnx and cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1)You can use RestKit to parse the data and create User model objects. 
2)Instead of chocolate create User (class/model) and properties (what you receive in HTTP response api). 
3) Reference this object in your UITableviewcontroller and initialize it.
4) Then you have array of User objects with data and count to create section, rows and cell.

Look at this tutorial too http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial

If you follow this I think you should get it.